# System.IO.FileLoadException during loading .NET assembly: error 0x8007007a

Tags: c#, .net, binding, .net-assembly, fuslogvw

We are having an issue related to starting a few in house developed .NET applications on Windows 10 Version 1607 machines. Sometimes starting an application doesn't succeed. This is because loading a dependent .NET assembly fails. The error message is:

> System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly
>   '[assemblyname], Version=[version], Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=[publickeytoken]' or one of its dependencies.  The data
>   area passed to a system call is too small. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x8007007A)

The issue happens about 10% of the application startups in different .NET applications. It happens with 32-bit as well as 64-bit applications. During all the startups also many other applications start that start up OK. I wonder why we get the `0x8007007a` error? Maybe it is collateral due to a heap corruption that happened before?

You can see related logging from FUSLOGVW below. The filepaths and assembly names are anonymised. The assembly that is attempted to be loaded has quite a long name (59 characters without the .dll postfix). As a test, we changed the name of the assembly to a shorter name. Unfortunately the issue remained. Adding a probing path in the exe.config also did not fix the issue.

Furthermore, there seems to be code of an older version of the Microsoft Assembly Resolver available at Github: https://github.com/fixdpt/shared-source-cli-2.0. I suspect there is something wrong in the ConstructCodeBaseList in adlmgr.cpp. But I can't figure out what triggers the issue.

```
*** Assembly Binder Log Entry  (2020/01/30 @ 13:48) ***

The operation failed.
Bind result: hr = 0x8007007a. The data area passed to a system call is too small.

Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Running under executable  C:\Program Files (x86)\XXX\XXX\XX.X.X.X\XXX\XXXXXXXXXXXXXX\ApplicationWeWantToStart.exe
--- A detailed error log follows. 

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = AnAssem.blyWi.th.AVeryLon.gNameAA.AAAAAAAA.AAAAAAAAAAA.AAAA, Version=13.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/XXX/XXX/XX.X.X.X/XXX/XXXXXXXXXXXXXX/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
LOG: Dynamic Base = NULL
LOG: Cache Base = NULL
LOG: AppName = ApplicationWeWantToStart.exe
Calling assembly : ApplicationWeWantToStart, Version=13.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Program Files (x86)\XXX\XXX\XX.X.X.X\XXX\XXXXXXXXXXXXXX\ApplicationWeWantToStart.exe.Config
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Post-policy reference: AnAssem.blyWi.th.AVeryLon.gNameAA.AAAAAAAA.AAAAAAAAAAA.AAAA, Version=13.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
LOG: GAC Lookup was unsuccessful.
ERR: Error occurred constructing the probing codebase list.
ERR: Unrecoverable error occurred during pre-download check (hr = 0x8007007a).
```

Answer (score 0):

Any change your startup issue may be related to this [Microsoft Support Link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4073393/fix-the-data-area-passed-to-a-system-call-is-too-small-error-when-you)